# Postgres stuck with ALTER query onp roduction

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

So I have this big database in production having partitions on date field.
I ran this migration to add a new column and its now 1-hour db is stuck not responding and still migrating.

```
ALTER TABLE public.ur_sms_traffic ADD COLUMN trace_id varchar(16);
```

The table has no relation. just stand-alone table,

Comment: Most likely it's waiting to acquire the needed exclusive lock. Check `pg_stat_activity` and `pg_locks`

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue by checking  `pg_stat_activity`: someone ran a very big query in production and it was holding the migration.